# When is the effect of skew most potent for an early exercise option?

Tags: options, option-pricing, local-volatility, volatility-skew, bermudan

Let us say I have a Bermudan option which I can terminate at 3 possible dates. When can I expect the discrepancy between a local vol and a stochastic vol model to be highest (assuming both are calibrated to vanillas)?

Intuitively, If the probability of exercise at any point is virtually 1, it is like a call option whose value will be the same for both models. However I'm not able to visualise beyond that.